# c++: Why is callback executed but function before callback definition not?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, callback, boost-thread

I am wondering why a function doWork() is called without the upper code being exectued. The code is the following:

```
void doWork()
{
std::cout<<"Hello World>";
sleep(1);
doWork();
}

....

void foo()
{
std:cout<<"This is text is never seen in the console but doWork timer callback works";
std::thread thread([&]{doWork();});
}
```

Why is std:cout not working but std::thread is being executed?

Thanks

Comment: There is an error as well. std:cout should be std::cout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't flush the buffer. Try adding `<< std::flush` or `<< std::endl` at the end.
2. You need to wait for execution in the thread to finish before the object `thread` is destructed.

   ```
   thread.join(); // Wait for thread to finish.
   ```
3. You don't need to capture everything as references in the lambda (`[&]`). You don't seem to use any of those captures.
4. If you're using the portable C++11 `std::thread` library, don't use Linux-specific `sleep` function. Instead use `std::this_thread::sleep_for`, e.g:

   ```
   void doWork() {             // (1. Flush buffer here too)
       std::cout << "Hello World>" << std::flush;
                               // 4. Use portable sleep.
       std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
       doWork();
   }

   // ....

   void foo() {
                               // 1. Flush buffer.
       std::cout << "This text is seen in the console" << std::endl;
       std::thread thread([] { // 3. No need to capture everything by reference
           doWork();
       });
       thread.join();          // 2. Wait for thread to finish.
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

cout is buffered, if the buffer is not flushed it will not immediately print.

You can use:

```
std::cout << "Text" << std::endl;
```

Or:

```
std::cout << "Text\n" << std::flush;
```

To flush the buffer.